# How to use Akka.net with router

Tags: c#, akka.net

I have started using akka.net but it is going very slow. So basically what I have is:

Http call that generates between 10 and 100 requests.

those requests objects are sent to an actor:

```
 var system = ActorSystem.Create("MySystem");
                    var searcher = system.ActorOf<generalSearchActor>("searcherAll");
                    searcher.Tell(sortedRequests);
```

Then inside the actor, I created a router and tell the router all the requests:

```
public generalSearchActor()
{
    Receive<List<HotelAvRequest>>(searchList =>
    {
        try { 
        Props props = new RoundRobinPool(5).Props(Props.Create<providerSearchActor>());
        var system = ActorSystem.Create("MySystem");
        var searcher = system.ActorOf(props, "searcher");

        foreach (var reques in searchList)
        {

            searcher.Tell(reques);

        }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            string a = "";
        }
    }
  );
}
```

It is working, but it takes a lot to process. No remote added so far.

I am sorry, I know that there is documentation but I just not sure if i am doing something wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be initializing two separate actor systems. One at the beginning and another one inside your `generalSearchActor`. This is likely the cause for the slow down you're experiencing.

Akka.net is supposed to work with a hierarchical actor structure. By initializing the actor system you automatically create the top level actor, then other actors should follow as either children of the top actor or children of other children (they can be nested multiple times).

You correctly create the child of the top level actor here:

```
var system = ActorSystem.Create("MySystem");
var searcher = system.ActorOf<generalSearchActor>("searcherAll");
searcher.Tell(sortedRequests);
```

However to create another actor from within an actor you have to use the `Context` property:

```
Props props = new RoundRobinPool(5).Props(Props.Create<providerSearchActor>());
var searcher = Context.ActorOf(props, "searcher");
```

The resulting actor hierarchy will look similar to:

- *MySystem/user/searcherAll*
- *MySystem/user/searcherAll/searcher*
- *MySystem/user/searcherAll/searcher/c1*
- *MySystem/user/searcherAll/searcher/c2*
- *MySystem/user/searcherAll/searcher/c3*
- *MySystem/user/searcherAll/searcher/c4*
- *MySystem/user/searcherAll/searcher/c5*

*searcherAll* - this is an instance of the `generalSearchActor`, it's a child of the top level actor.

*searcher* - this is the router actor, it's a child of the *searcherAll* actor.

*c1* through *c5* - those are the instances of `providerSearchActor` spawned by the *searcher* router, they are his children.